# How to render multiple widgets in flutter according to data from a list?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, conditional-rendering

I'm new to flutter. I have to render widgets according to an API response, which is JSON in a list.
This is one of the custom widgets I have written for it. I have one for every row.

```
Widget testwidget2() {
      return FutureBuilder<List<inspectionOrder>>(
        future: createIO_Service.viewinspection_Service(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<inspectionOrder> data = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: data.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 50,
                    child: Center(child: Text(data[index].RoomType)),
                  );
                });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      );
    }
```

I use a series of rows inside a listview to render these widgets.

```
ListView(
          // decoration: BoxDecoration(
          // border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent,width: 5)),
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
         children: <Widget>[
       Row(
           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
         Expanded( child: workordertile()),
```

But the problem is the whole data is rendered in one go (See Picture 1). But I want it to be rendered as shown in the second picture. The application in the second picture is written ionic, of which I have no idea at all. [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzUo8.jpg)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qni9u.jpg)

Comment: you mean you want its ui to be like second one?

Comment: Yes!! Exactly, that's what i want

Comment: well you should go step by step, first try to make a white background like the image then try to make  to make other pieces , if you don't know how to , you can ask them one by one , with this question , you want a bunch of widgets and edit, it is not a big deal, but if you ask them one by one you will get the answer sooner ,you can start with this `how to overlay a widget to a container`  and so on......

Comment: Thanks for the tip Yahya. If you are interested in the solution, I have added a solution I found out on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

you should use "**lazyloading**(pagination,etc)"
you can use this package:https://pub.dev/packages/pagination